# XAMPP load blank screen on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, localhost

I'm using XAMPP as my localhost server testing, and I'm using the CodeIgniter PHP framework for my web app.

When I want to test my web application, XAMPP doesn't load properly.
I've been waiting around a minute, and then what I get is just blank screen on the browser page.

I really need a local testing. But, oddly my CodeIgniter does work very well on my web hosting; no errors at all.

I'm using XAMPP v3.2.1, and my PHP version is 5.6.3.

Is there any custom configuration I should do?

And one more thing: this blank screen only appears when the model is trying to fetch data from database.

I have tested things like "Hello world" and it works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your web hosting running PHP 5.6 as well?

Comment: I'm using wamp server now, and it's running with no problem as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blank page is likely due to PHP errors with directives to display errors turned off. Check your php.ini for *display_errors*, *html_errors* and *error_reporting* directives. Should be:

```
display_errors = On
html_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

Answer (score 0):

Because 
* Your XAMPP works (because HelloWord program run correctly)
* Your web application on real server works.
 You check your **routing configuration**.

See more: https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

(Try checking HTML source from blank page what you have seen, try enter url *domain_at_localhost/[controler]/[action]/[param1]/[param2]...* manually, and see result.)

Comment: I have but, it just appear the same. And the source was blank too. Thanks anyway. This things just happen, whenever the function trying to read database.

Comment: Ok, check/change database configuration from **your_real_domain** ----> **localhost** or other virtual host alias. Check `application/config/database.php`. Reference: https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html